# Prompt for text optional in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

In a dialog, I added a "Prompt for text" to request user feedback. I want to make this prompt optional, the expected behavior is for users to decide if they want to give feedback or not.
I don't find a way to do this.
I'm using Bot Framework Composer v2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would use an initial "prompt for confirmation" block and then an if/else block. This will allow you to have a yes/no option in chat that you can use for "would you like to provide input?", then only if the user clicks yes will they be prompted to input text.